# Replace file extension with folder in htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to reformat a url with the structure

http://www.example.com/vaservice/ServiceController.svc?v1=d1&v2=d2&...

to

http://www.example.com/vaservice/ServiceController/svc?v1=d1&v2=d2&...

I have removed the .svc from the url with this htaccess code but I cannot figure out how to replace the . with a / instead of just removing the extension.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.svc [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.svc -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.svc [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out thanks!

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.svc [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/svc [R,L]`